# How to realize user authorization and session mechanism in Cowboy?

Tags: session, erlang, cowboy

In my project I need user authorization. Could you a hint me ways to realize a session in Cowboy server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a look at cowboy_session: https://github.com/chvanikoff/cowboy_session

Answer (score 0):

The same way as anywhere else. If you want to just differentiate users set a cookie to something like `crypto:rand_bytes()`. If you need to store some session information and is fine too put it in a cookie  you can encrypt and hmac `term_to_binary()` and store it in a cookie.

Comment: Do you propose to crypt user information (like name, authorization status and role) and store it in a cookie? I suppose that user data is stored in the ets-table and uuid is stored in a cookie. But in this way appears issue with session timeout.

Comment: It's already standard to store session data on client. Encrypting and signing provide a secure way of not introducing central database at least for session management.